# Angular Reactive Form: Using a FormArray and adjusting the FormControls leads to Error There is no form control element for path

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I'm creating a filterable table. The first column contains checkboxes for selecting rows, and eventually the user can do some actions with the selections.

On filter, I am doing:

```
public resetFormRows(items: any[]) {
    this.formGroup.removeControl('rows');
    const newRows = items.map(_ => new FormControl(false));
    const newFormArray = new FormArray(newRows);
    this.formGroup.addControl('rows', newFormArray);
}
```

After filtering the table, I can console.log the controls and see that the FormArray contains the new FormControl. However, when I select the checkbox for a row that shifted (i.e. changed row index), the following error is shown:

> ERROR Error: There is no FormControl instance attached to form control
> element with path: 'rows -> 1'

Here is a stackblitz that demonstrates the bug:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8-template-form-fzsyse?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable.component.ts

To get the error to show, perform the following:

- Select filter checkbox: "Has Owner?"
- Select checkbox for "Stapler"

I have a few questions:

- why am I getting this error and why does my console.log show a FormControl but the error says I don't have one?
- The error stacktrace doesn't point me to anything specific in my codebase. So, how do people typically debug these issues?

Comment: this is weird actually, if you replace `i` with 1, it works, I am not suggesting that's a fix, I am just curious about the behavior

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using formControlName directive, try using formControl standalone directive as mentioned in the [thread](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14057):

**Try this:**

```
    <tr *ngFor="let item of filteredData$ | async; index as i">
        <td>
            <label><input type="checkbox" checkBoxDirective [formControl]="myForm.get('rows').controls[i]" /></label>
        </td>
        <td>
            {{ item.name }}     
        </td> 
    </tr>
```

[Forked Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-reactive-form-using-a-formarray-and-adjusting-the-formc?file=src/app/table.component.html)

Comment: Thank you! Works as intended

Answer (score 1):

your form array contains formcontrols but they dont have any name so you can not access them using formControlName

to fix this:

in ts:

```
  get formArray() {
      return this.myForm.controls.rows as FormArray;
  }
```

in html

```
<input type="checkbox" checkBoxDirective [formControl]="formArray.controls[i]" />
```

working stackblitz link :

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8-template-form-8xnmdp?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable.component.html